# HBase & JDBC Connection

Tags: java, jdbc, hbase

I am a newbie in HBase and I am trying to connect to HBase thru JDBC (Working on a Java based application). Can I connect to HBase from the PC client directly via JDBC (I am using Netbeans for the Java applications) or do I need to install any additional packages to connect to the HBase Region Server. I am using EMC's Pivotal Hadoop.

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding HBase is a noSQL database. so, to use JDBC you need an SQL layer to access HBase. I don't know if you can use hive or pig to do that, but for me phoenix is working just fine
http://phoenix.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

Use Hive over Hbase.

Hive do have a JDBC Driver "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"
and ("jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default", "", "") is the Database schema.